# Environment help for CAA Rade

Tags: c++, visual-studio, caa

I am new to CAA rade and programming within the integrated environment on Visual Studio 2005. I am wondering if there is any great resource/book that can introduce me to this platform. Every time I start exploring the encyclopedia or Visual studio I end up with losing hope. All I want is a relevant resource that helps with introducing to this environment. Any walkthroughs for creating cpp files, EXPRESS schemas, using external libraries etc would help me. People say that it is easy to program in CAA but I am unable to figure out my need bits. Just I need an introduction to a hello world program, and few samples so that I can get comfortable with it.

regards,
sghz0f

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way learning CAA is the academic program of the dassault systemes. CAA programmers are only few in the world. So, it must be a tough way to develop CAA. Good luck.

by the way, I've been seen your question in dassault systemes forum. That site can't be relied on at all.

Comment: And there are a lot of sample codes in CAA V5 encyclopaedia.
(looking for your CAA installation path: C:\(install path)\CAADoc\Doc\online\CAACenV5Default.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Digging into the CAA documentation, I found:

```
   CATIA_INSTALLATION_DIR/CAADoc/Doc/online/CAADocUseCases/CAADocRunSample.htm
```

This seems a good starting point to set up the environment and start coding. However, not many introduction courses are available online. Probably, the developer community is quite small.

Answer (score 1):

As Nic mentioned there is very less CAA developer and there is no online stuff available for the same. What you can do is to start with basics of COM and then move on to Addins, Command, and Dialog. You can use CAA help viewer.

`CAA Directory/CAADoc/Doc/online/CAACenV5Default.htm` will be your best friend :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Dougen.
If you have CAA RADE licence, you would probably have access to Dassault systemes documentation on CAA. That would be the best place to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Another good place to get started could be community CAA2 Version6 Development that was launched by Dassault Systèmes at the beginning of October 2011.

Visit http://www.3ds.com/partners/software-partnership/partners-resources-and-services/ to know more. Please not however that check for valid professional email addresses and valid licenses are performed.

Regards.